Cannot connect Looker Studio to Postgres Database hosted in Google Cloud SQL
I am trying to connect to Looker Studio my Postgres Database that is hosted in Google Cloud SQL using the PostgreSQL google connector for days and have the same problem: " Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your request. Error ID: 3323e234"
My database has SSL certificates.

Host Name: The Public IP address found in Google Cloud SQL Instance
Port: 5432
Database:  foo-database
Username: postgres
Password: ****

I have ticked "Enable SSL" and "Enable Client authentication" and imported the certificates that I use to also connect to PGAdmin.
I have included the 142.251.74.0/23 address as instructed in the docs in the Authorized networks of my db.
I still cant connect and cant find why.
Any ideas?

Can you clarify or link to the PostgreSQL google connector? Are you using one of the Cloud SQL Language Connectors?
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-connectors

I just go to Looker Studio > Create Data Source > PostgreSQL.
https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/7288010#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

have the same issue. did you solve it?

Nope. Just shifted to Metabase.

You are probably using a more recent version of PostgreSQL that is not supported by Looker Studio. As of this moment latest supported version is 14: https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/7288010?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article
They seem to have recently added support for version 15 based on our tests though this is not documented yet.

My Database version is PostgreSQL 13.15, so that's probably not it. Something is wrong with the SSL certificates I think, but after searching for days, I just gave up and used Metabase which I setup in 30 minutes. Nice thinking though, I didn't check that
